# Plugins as actor in UML use case diagram

Tags: uml, actor, modeling, use-case

As the title says, lets say chrome is under development knowing that once it is ready, developpers allover the word can create plugins it.

The question is, are the plugins actors of the system Chrome ? 
So, do I draw a use case diagram where chrome is the system and "plugin" is an actor?

This knowing that the user of chrome does never interact with the plugin. For exemple a plugin that record your stats and give them to alexa directly maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, plug-in is an actor (system actor) in this case (supposing that chrome itself is under development).

The fact that a human user does not interact with the plug-in does not change this. Use case(s) associated to this actor (Plug-in) make up the Chrome plugin API, so everything is ok.

Even if there were some interaction between the plugin and a human user, this would not be shown on the use case model in this configuration (chrome under development), because this human users would be far out of system boundaries, with no direct connection to the system itself.

Another situation would be in case of the changed use case context. If you decide to make a use case model of the plugin, than a Chrome would be an actor and every additional human user of this plugin as well.